# AdMob with Cocos2d v3

Tags: ios, sdk, cocos2d-iphone, admob

I am trying to integrate AdMob banner with Cocos2d v3 project but no luck:(

All documentation samples and tutorials are for the old cocos version and do not compile.

Any samples or successful experience?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is my [Cocos2d 3.0 Admob Baner Sample](https://app.box.com/s/7lsxp9u4lam2rym6i2x8).

In AppDelegate.h, define banner type on your need basis.

```
typedef enum _bannerType
{
    kBanner_Portrait_Top,
    kBanner_Portrait_Bottom,
    kBanner_Landscape_Top,
    kBanner_Landscape_Bottom,
}CocosBannerType;

#define BANNER_TYPE kBanner_Portrait_Top
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thank you! You've helped a lot