# Switching between ad networks in cocos2d v3.0 and spritebuilder

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, admob, iad, revmob

as the title would suggest i'm trying to make a system that automatically will prioritize my ad networks and display the next in line when one fails to load. I currently have iAd implemented and working following this example: [How to add iad in cocos2d?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17815777/how-to-add-iad-in-cocos2d/17816415#17816415) and I plan on using the example provided by the same person, Guru, to implement AdMob. Example found here: [AdMob with Cocos2d v3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21846346/admob-with-cocos-2d-v3). Now preferably I would like to just add on/change the working code as it is very well built and organized. Along with prioritizing iAd followed by AdMob, I would like to also have revmob as well. I was thinking of just doing revmob as the fullscreen ad when launched, but I would still like to know how I would go about adding the revmob banners to the rotation just as good measure. If any of my code is needed I'll gladly post it :)

Comment: Okay, so I assume all of these APIs provide an error callback method. So when that error callback runs, load the next ad network view and check for any errors. You should narrow down your question, right now this seems a little like a "please write the code for me" kind of question.

Comment: I have it working, wasn't hard and your pointer lead me in the right direction. Only question I have is should I add a hide method for Admob in iAds: bannerViewDidLoadAd method? Or should it not matter as admob will only load when it fails? I just dont want them to be overlapping or some other weird issue, what do you suggest?