# How much space should I leave out for a bottom Admob banner?

Tags: c++, cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0, cocos2d-android

I left out about 100(don't know the unit) in height at the bottom of the screen for the admob banner, which will be added at the end of the project.

For iphone 6, the height of the admob banner is about 100.

But, when I move to ipad, this height is different.

So some elements differ in position (in height direction).

For example:

```
float admobHeight = 100.0;

Vec2 desiredPosition = Vec2(0, 100);

auto sprite = Sprite::create("image.png");
sprite->setAnchorPoint(Vec2(0, 0));

// Leave out space for the bottom Admob banner.
sprite->setPosition(Vec2(desiredPosition.x, desiredPosition.y + admobHeight));

this->addChild(sprite);
```

I set DesignResolution as :

```
(AppDelegate.cpp)

static cocos2d::Size designResolutionSize = cocos2d::Size(768, 1136);
```

and Resolution policy NO_BORDER:

```
glview->setDesignResolutionSize(designResolutionSize.width, designResolutionSize.height, ResolutionPolicy::NO_BORDER);
```

How can I leave out just right amount of space in height at the bottom of my screen for Admob for every type of devices?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/ads/AdSize

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21846346/admob-with-cocos2d-v3/21859218#21859218

Answer (score 0):

standard banner height is 60px
here is the code for admob banner integration

bannerView_ = [[GADBannerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,  viewController.view.frame.size.height-60, viewController.view.frame.size.width, 60)];
        bannerView_.center = CGPointMake( viewController.view.frame.size.width/2.f, viewController.view.frame.size.height-30 );
        bannerView_.adUnitID = ADMOB_BANNER_ID;

```
    bannerView_.rootViewController=self.viewController;

    //[UIViewController:addSubview:bannerView_];
    [viewController.view addSubview:bannerView_];
    // Initiate a generic request to load it with an ad.
    [bannerView_ loadRequest:[GADRequest request]];
```